# color ggplot using specific pallette

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I color the plots such that -

A1 - Dark blue,
A2 - Light blue,
B1 - Dark red,
B2 - Light red

```
tbl <- tibble(x = c(rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                    rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 0.5),
                    rnorm(n = 100, mean = 4, sd = 1),
                    rnorm(n = 100, mean = 4, sd = 0.5)),
              y = c(rep("A1", 100),
                    rep("A2", 100),
                    rep("B1", 100), 
                    rep("B2", 100))
              )

              
ggplot(data = tbl, 
       aes(x = x,
           fill = y)) + 
  geom_histogram(color = "black",
                 alpha = 0.5) + 
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I arbitrarily chose the colors (Dark blue ~ Light Red).
You can change the colors manually using hexcode in `sclae_fill_manual`.

```r
tbl <- tibble(x = c(rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                    rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 0.5),
                    rnorm(n = 100, mean = 4, sd = 1),
                    rnorm(n = 100, mean = 4, sd = 0.5)),
              y = c(rep("A1", 100),
                    rep("A2", 100),
                    rep("B1", 100), 
                    rep("B2", 100))
)


ggplot(data = tbl, 
       aes(x = x,
           fill = y)) + 
  geom_histogram(color = "black",
                 alpha = 0.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#2C3FF6','#72B5FC','#F62C2C','#F0C3C3'))+
  theme_bw()
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer above but a little more verbose using a named vector of colors.

```
    # Create a named vector of colors
    # There is no R color named "light red" therefore I used red instead. 
    colours <- c(A1= "darkblue", A2="lightblue", B1= "darkred", B2= "red")

    ggplot(data = tbl, 
           aes(x = x,
               fill = y)) + 
      geom_histogram(color = "black",
                     alpha = 0.5) + 
      scale_fill_manual(values = colours) +
      theme_bw()
```